# How do I select a href variable that is in a while loop?

Tags: javascript, php, href, attr

I have a while loop that select multiple images from a database. I have a link with a href and there is a function when it's clicked, it will open up a video modal box. Right now it's only selecting the first href link no matter which one is selected. How do I make sure it's the proper href rather than only the first one?

PHP: this part works fine.

```
while ($row = $q->fetch()): 

?>

  <li class="item <?php echo $row['type'];?>"><a href="<?php echo $row['link'];?>" class="test-popup-link">
  <?php if($row['img']) { ?>
  <img src="upload/videoCovers/<?php echo $row['img'];?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title'];?>">
  <?php } 
        else { ?>
  <img src="upload/videoCovers/playBtn.png" alt="<?php echo $row['title'];?>">
  <?php } ?>
  </a>
  </li>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var videoLink = $(".test-popup-link").attr("href");

    $('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        items: {
          src: videoLink
        },
        type: 'iframe' // this is default type
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about that plugin but, you'll probably want to loop through all the elements with the `.test-popup-link` class and invoke `.magnificPopup()`. Consider the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.test-popup-link').each(function() {
      $(this).magnificPopup({
          items: {
            src: $(this).attr('href')
          },
          type: 'iframe' // this is default type
      });
    });
});
```

**Edit**: After a quick look at the [Magnific Popup Documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html), it looks like you can use the following example as well.

> [...] Use this method if you are creating a popup from a list of elements in one container. Note that this method does not enable gallery mode, it just reduces the number of click event handlers; each item will be opened as a single popup

*html*

```
<div class="parent-container">
  <a href="path-to-image-1.jpg">Open popup 1</a>
  <a href="path-to-image-2.jpg">Open popup 2</a>
  <a href="path-to-image-3.jpg">Open popup 3</a>
</div>
```

*javascript*

```
$('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
  type: 'image'
  // other options
});
```

So in your case, you may want to consider targeting the `ul` parent to your list.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your first suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: Np! @MikeCerveni if this solution worked for you, please feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This will help let others know so they do not continue providing answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me point out few problems in your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var videoLink = $(".test-popup-link").attr("href"); // ( 1 )

    $('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({               //( 2 )
        items: {
          src: videoLink                                //( 3 )
        },
        type: 'iframe' // this is default type
    });
});
```

1. `$(".test-popup-link").attr("href");`  Here the code `$(".test-popup-link")` will return you all the elements with the class `test-popup-link`, so you will get a collection of nodes, which is fine. Now when you do `.attr("href")` **only the first node in the collection is selected and its href is returned**.
2. You are trying to apply the plugin to all the elements with the class `test-popup-link` which is fine unless the inner configurations of the plugin is the same. In your case it varies in the `videoLink` value, So you cannot use it in a generic way. **You have to use a loop to apply plugin**.
3. As mentioned above,  your `videoLink` hold only the first elements href and only this **first href value will be applied to all**.

So the **solution would be to use a loop to apply the plugin**. Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $.each('.test-popup-link',function() { //looping
      $(this).magnificPopup({              // apply to each element in the loop
          items: {
            src: $(this).attr('href')      // apply its respective href
          },
          type: 'iframe' // this is default type
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.load-video').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var link = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        items: {
          src: link
        },
        type: 'iframe' // this is default type
    });
});
```

add class in **a** tag

```
<a class="load-video test-popup-link" href="<?php echo $row['link'];?>">
```

Comment: Why register an additional click handler? This seems like useless overhead.

Comment: i think for open modal, magnificPopup have default click to open ? because i not use magnific

Comment: I don't use magnific either but, one can assume that a click handler is being registered once `magnificPopup()` is invoked. Based on OP, clicking on the first element works as expected. So your answer really doesn't accomplish anything other than registering a click handler upon click.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help! It works now perfectly. Appreciate everyone's input.